# Send commands to vim programmatically

Tags: javascript, vim

I'd like to build an interface in Javascript where I collect key presses and send them to a remote vim instance and have the instance report back any changes. I'm quite confident I can implement all of the browser-server communication and javascript --- I'm just not sure how to pass the data to vim and how to have it talk back to me.

Any pointers would be appreciated! Thanks

**Edit**: An initial implementation can be found on [Github](https://github.com/honza/vim.io).

Comment: Never tried it, but if you compile vim with [`+clientserver` support](http://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/remote.html) it can be run in client-server mode. See [this blog post](http://ajayfromiiit.wordpress.com/2009/10/21/server-and-client-mode-in-vim/) for a simple example.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Take a look at [TextAid](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/ppoadiihggafnhokfkpphojggcdigllp/details) (specifically the Perl server). Maybe you'll find useful ideas.

*--RE-EDIT--*

Since I like your idea I've looked a bit further.

Supposing Vim is compiled with `+clientserver`, you can launch vim like this:

```
$ vim --servername MYSERVER /path/to/tempfile`
```

on your remote box. Vim is launched in server mode and you can send it commands like:

```
$ vim --servername MYSERVER --remote-send 'ihello<Esc>'
```

to have:

```
hello
```

on the first line, if you send:

```
$ vim --servername MYSERVER --remote-send 'A world<Esc>'
```

you obtain:

```
hello world
```

If you send:

```
$ vim --servername MYSERVER --remote-send 'yy5p'
```

you obtain:

```
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
hello world
```

If you send:

```
$ vim --servername MYSERVER --remote-send ':%s/hello/goodbye cruel<CR>'
```

you obtain:

```
goodbye cruel world
goodbye cruel world
goodbye cruel world
goodbye cruel world
goodbye cruel world
```

which is kind of cool but you need to send back the new state of the buffer which you would do by writing the temporary file and sending its content back to the client **after** each command. That means a lot of read/write on your server. One could also write a macro that sends the content of the buffer to some external process on each "change".

*--EDIT--*

If you had followed the link instead of dismissing my answer you would have seen that the extension above works by sending the content of the textarea to the Perl server via HTTP.

I don't think it matters at all if Vim is local or on a distant server.

The server writes it into a temporary file that is then opened with Vim.

When Vim writes the file, its content is then sent back to the extension by the server.

Your piece of JS would do what the extension does: grab the content of the textarea, send it via an AJAX POST request to your server, wait for an answer and update the content of the textarea with it.

Actually, I think that you could even use the script above as is. Or at least take it as a starting point for your own app.

Comment: I want to build a cloud vim editor, not a local machine utility. Thanks

Comment: Please update your question. Nothing in it says that you want to build a cloud Vim. What is a cloud Vim, anyway?

Comment: I assure you that I did click through to the extension detail page when you first posted the answer. And I did just now to make sure I hadn't read it wrong. You still misunderstand what I'm trying to do. The extension opens the content of the textarea in vim; the content gets to vim via HTTP. That I know how to do. A cloud vim is something like Akshell or 8 IDE --- an IDE in the browser. Except this one has *real* vim bindings because it's processed by a real vim backend.

Comment: OK, you should have said that right from the beginning: I misunderstood what you want to do because you didn't explain it. Two things come to my mind: 1) Vim has a lot of keybindings, augmenting a textarea with listeners and custom methods for all of them would obviously require more than a few Mb of JS. That's probably why the other client-side editors you mention don't do that and also why the many client-side Vim emulators don't do that either. From that point of view I think your idea is good. 2) For sending commands to a running Vim, see `:help remote.txt`, the `FUNCTIONS` chapter.

Comment: My apologies. The re-edit is brilliant. Thanks for taking the time.

Comment: Upon closer inspection, it looks like a graphical instance of vim is required in order to run the above commands. The scenario where a headless instance is running on the server won't work.

Comment: No, I have it working with two instances of CLI Vim 7.2 in two Gnome Terminal windows on my Ubuntu 10.10 desktop. It certainly depends on a couple of compile flags because it doesn't work at my office on my Mac using the CLI Vim provided by MacVim or on my playground linode.